# How do I access specific tags in Kanna using Swift?

Tags: html, swift, html-parsing

How do I retrieve the information in this html row:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://wines.nob/red-wines-upp-till-99-usd/25-montepulciano-d-abruzzo" />
```

I want to get hold of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way of doing it, don't know if it's the best way?

```
 for link in doc.xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']") {
     let urlLink = link["content"]
     print("Link: \(urlLink ?? "No link")")
 }
```